# gwt-servlet.jar missing in the WEB-INF/lib on compiling GWT with maven

Tags: eclipse, gwt, maven

In my pom file, I have included the dependency of gwt-servlet but if i run `mvn clean install` and `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and open the project in eclipse, I get the following error

> GWT SDK JAR gwt-servlet.jar is missing in the WEB-INF/lib directory

**EDIT :**
Here is my dependency (we use a custom maven repository):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.smartgwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>smart-gwt</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

**EDIT 2 (main pom):**

```
<build>
    <extensions>
      <extension>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-ftp</artifactId>
      </extension>
    </extensions>
....
```

Comment: what's the dependency scope (compile, provided..)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things I noticed.

1) The smartgw dependency you specified cannot be resolved from the maven central repository

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.smartgwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>smart-gwt</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

It only has the 2.4 version of smartgw (see here http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Csmartgwt) Instead I had to use this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.smartgwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>smartgwt</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

notice that the artifact ID is different too. (If you have a custom repository containing this then please update your question)

2) You dont need to do eclipse:eclipse instead you can issue the

File > Import > Existing Maven projects

this will auto generate the eclipse project from your pom.xml

**UPDATE**

I tested with the following :

Parent pom in gwttest2 folder

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwttest2-main</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>gwttest2-module1</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                <artifactId>wagon-ftp</artifactId>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
    </build>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.smartgwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>smartgwt</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

child pom in gwttest2/gwttest2-module1 folder

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwttest2-module1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>gwttest2-main</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                <artifactId>wagon-ftp</artifactId>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
    </build>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.smartgwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>smartgwt</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. Yes we use our own repository. Will running the **File > Import > Existing Maven projects** solve the missing library thing?

Comment: it solved the problem for me, but let me know if this is not the case for you.

Comment: doing what you said generated the following error:
**Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Error resolving version for plugin 'org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-ftp' from the repositories [local (*), central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository**

Comment: @AdelBoutros Looks like the version of your wagon-ftp is either incorrect or not set at all (or eclipse cannot access it from your plugin repository) Seems like you have a slightly more complex pom.xml then you posted :) Could you update your post with the missing parts for example the part where you use wagon-ftp, and any pluginrepository reference if you have one

Comment: if the version of ftp is incorrect or not set then the code shouldn't work from mvn install and mvn eclipse:eclipse. That's what wierd. Sadly, I cannot post everything because the code is confidential. This is all i can show (check the update). I have a directory containing many projects and each project has a pom and there is a general pom at the root of the directory which contains the **wagon-ftp** dependency.

Comment: @AdelBoutros unfortunately without the full pom it is not possible to reproduce so you will need to go on by yourself :) I would say you can start two directions :

Comment: 1) if you say your project can be build from the command line then check what version of Maven are you using from eclipse (window/preference/maven/installation) by default it uses Maven3 which is known to cause troubles. Change it to use Maven 2.

Comment: 2) If there are still problems then try to create a test project and gradually add complexity into it and see where it fails. I created a test project with parent and child pom and wagon-ftp and managed to import it to eclipse without any problem. You can see my pom files in my post. you can just create the folders and put the pom files in it dont need any additional java classes or so...

Comment: I am currently working on another project and am unable to further verify this issue until the end of January. Regardless of this fact, in appreciation of your time and effort I will accept your answer and award you the bounty. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Tell Eclipse to use Maven dependencies by right-clicking on your Project folder and selecting

***Configure > Convert to Maven Project.***

It seems that even after running mvn eclipse:eclipse, you must do this manually to get Eclipse to actually let Maven take care of your dependencies.

If you don't see this option you may not have the M2Eclipse plugin installed in your Eclipse...

Comment: I know ti can be done this way. I was wondering if there is a fix to make work only using **mvn eclipse:eclipse**

Comment: We do this successfully with our WARs, but all our dependencies are scope=provided and those dependencies are put in the EAR.  The only bug we've found with eclipse:eclipse is that it adds a META-INF folder (in a generated source) folder to the sources dirs causing eclipse to complain.