# Gwt-servlet.jar had error when import project from bitbucket

Tags: java, eclipse, git, gwt

We are making a project and push it into bitbucket.
When i import it from git to another computer i get errors to the file gwt-servlet.jar and i don't know why.
There is some way to edit it and make it adaptative for each computer that download it?

How can i solve this problem?

I see this link but can't see how can solve my problem [Another discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564091/gwt-servlet-jar-missing-in-the-web-inf-lib-on-compiling-gwt-with-maven)

And can i push the file .classpath and .project? In the repo the file .classpath is missed and we need to paste into folder manually

Problem:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The file war\WEB-INF\lib\gwt-servlet.jar has a different size than GWT SDK library gwt-servlet.jar; perhaps it is a different version?  gwt-servlet.jar /QuestionAndAnswer/war/WEB-INF/lib  Unknown GWT Problem
```

Comment: What's the actual **error message**?

Comment: sorry i forget it, added in the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong gwt-servlet.jar in your WEB-INF/lib folder. Simply delete it, and pull the project again.

In general, it's not a good idea to include such files in your repository as they are part of the GWT SDK that you have to add to your build path anyway. Remove it from the repository, and make sure that all developers use the same GWT SDK.

Comment: And whats about the .project and .classpath into project folder in the repo?
They must be pushed or not?

Yes we have a different version of gwt sdk :( but the project is terminated now :D ....

We will delete if from the repository, but if we delete it, when we import the project from git we get errors because the file gwt-servlet.jar.... this is the problem :)

Comment: You can push any files into the repository, including .classpath and .project. Some things you can not solve with git only - you still have to configure your local environment/project.

Comment: Thanks i'm new with this Bitbucket and Git...they are more difficult than programming code :D :D

Answer (score 0):

I was faced the same issue with this message

"gwt-servlet.jar has a different size than GWT SDK library gwt-servlet.jar; perhaps it is a different version"

When i compiled the GWT compile the application was compiled correctly, but when i run the application in GWT subper dev mode it is given the message.

in this case i goes to build path jar "gwt-servlet.jar" and war/WEB-INF/lib folder jar "gwt-servlet.jar" verified, so it is sizes are different , so i updated the latest jar file updated to build path,

it solved my issues.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps for resolution:

1. Delete the Jar from Web-INF folder.
2. Download gwt-servlet.jar version 2.5.1.
3. Select project properties -> Java Build path -> Add External JARs
4. Select the gwt-servlet.jar and Apply
5. It will be by dafault available in Web-INF folder.

The compilation issue will be resolved. Happy Coding!